# How can I create a folder system inside of my python program?

Tags: python, directory

Is there any way to actually create a standalone file system in a python program? I know that you can use `os.mkdir()` and `os.chdir()` but these write directly to your actual system instead of being stored in the program. I've tried several ways to do this, including:

```
if command == ("md"):
    newDir = input("")
    with open('directories.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(newDir)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but I was wondering if anyone has some ideas on how one might do this. (This is for a basic but hopefully semi-function MS-DOS style os I'm working on.)

Comment: ... what problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Why not use the actual file system?

Comment: A simple solution coming to mind is creating a tree-like data structure, where the root is your / directory, and each node of the tree has a name, contains a list of directories it's holding, and list of files it's holding.

Comment: Something that `open`, `os.listdir` and friends would recognize? I don't think so. There are user mode RAM or file-system-in-file-system services out there. but those wouldn't be "in" the python program.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why writing to the file is a problem, but you could basically have a Tree type data structure to represent a file system. For example:

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, filename, directory=False):
        self.filename = filename
        self.directory = directory
        self.files = [] if directory else None
```

where `self.files` is a list of File objects that you can iterate through as a tree. This is obviously rudimentary and I'll leave a more detailed implementation up to you.